# How can I call ApplicationTokenProvider without making my call chain async?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have the same problem as this question:

[Call to ApplicationTokenProvider never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887805/call-to-applicationtokenprovider-loginsilentasync-never-returns)

The solution there is to make the calling method async, and presumably every call above it async. I've got this method deep in a call chain (that works fine in a test harness) and fails to return when called in an MVC Controller. I don't want to make every call above it async - it would require a lot of redesign and ugly architecture to introduce an async capability that is useless to my code.

Surely there is some way to make this just #$(*&# work synchronously? Here's my code currently:

```
public void Authenticate()
{
    var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(TenantId, ApplicationId, Secret).Result;
    var monitorClient = new MonitorManagementClient(serviceCreds) {SubscriptionId = SubscriptionId.ToString()};

    MonitorClient = monitorClient;
}
```

The call on line three to LoginSilentAsync never returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also can reproduce it on myside. I resolved it by implementing the custom ServiceClientCredentials. The following the demo code.

```
 public class CustomCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials
    {
        private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }

        public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
        {
            var authenticationContext =
                new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/yourtenantId");
            var credential = new ClientCredential("clientid", clientSecret: "secret key");

            var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/",
                credential).Result;

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }

            AuthenticationToken = result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
```

2.Change you Authenticate function to the following code.

```
 public void Authenticate()
        {
            var monitorClient = new MonitorManagementClient(new CustomCredentials()) { SubscriptionId = "subscription Id" };
            MonitorClient = monitorClient;
        }
```

3.Test it in the local.

[image]